# How can I return to normal view (View Track Waveforms) in Reaper

Tags: daw, cockos-reaper

I switched to "Peaks View" for moment. Now I can't get back to tracks looking like standard Waveforms. Will only show Peaks, Spectral Peaks, etc.

Anyone know how to get back to normal?

Answer (score 1):

Options: Peaks Display Mode : Show Normal Peaks